# how to convert a string " 1/2" into number 1/2 in R

Tags: r, string, numeric

I am having a variable holding value `a <- " 1/2"`. how to convert it into numeric value like this `b <- 1/2`. And from 'b' I want to extract 1.

is it possible to extract 1  from "a" without converting it into numeric?

Note: Here my string(a) contains space before 1.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10674992/324364

Answer (score 3):

We can use `eval(parse`

```
b <- eval(parse(text=a))
b
#[1] 0.5
```

This could be converted to `fractions` class using `library(MASS)`

```
library(MASS)
fractions(b)
#[1] 1/2
```

---

If the post is to remove the space alone

```
sub('^\\s+', '', a)
#[1] "1/2"
```

#### Update

If we need to extract 1 from 'a'.

```
 gsub('\\/.*|\\s+', '', a)
 #[1] "1"
```

Comment: I want to get 1 from b's value. is it possible to get this

Comment: @SurviMakharia  You can directly get it from `a` i.e. `gsub('\\/.*|\\s+', '', a)`